# Interval Algorithm for Gradient Descent Method

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Are there any references discussing an interval algorithm for the vanilla gradient descent method given a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$?

**Edit**: In particular, I am searching for an interval algorithm that bounds the path $\phi\bigl([0,t^*]\bigr)$ where $\phi$ is the solution to the ODE 
$$
\phi'(t) = -\nabla f\bigl(\phi(t)\bigr), \quad \phi(0)=x_0.
$$
There are plenty of interval ODE solvers but that is not sufficient for my purpose. I need more precise control over how big the intervals bounding the solution become and how they step.

Comment: Are you asking about a [line-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search) part of a gradient descent method, or something else?  Perhaps about [interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic)?

Comment: Yes, this algorithm should use interval arithmetic.